# Restarting all Hadoop nodes and master from command line

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have a 5-node Hadoop cluster, and if I want to do a full system restart of all Hadoop nodes when I know my entire cluster is quiet, can I simply run Unix `shutdown` commands and is there a generally optimal sequence in which to run those? By quiet, let's say I mean that no jobs have run on the cluster for 12 hours and none will run in the following 12 hours.  Whether the services are doing some internal maintenance is another issue of course.

Just based on the design of Hadoop, I would think it may not matter much and either "datanodes first then master" or "master first then datanodes" may both be perfectly fine.  It is after all a distributed system.

I would like a response that remains general in the sense of not getting into which management interfaces might be in use.  I'd like a response like, "such and such will generally work fine," as in barring pathological management interface issues.

We are utilizing HDFS, MapReduce, HBase, Kafka, and Zookeeper. Hive and Pig a bit as well.

Comment: I'm no hadoop expert, but don't you have to start the Hadoop processes manually? If you use the Unix shutdown, won't you manually have to restart each Hadoop process?

Comment: Well, if I reboot, it's a normal system configuration where it brings things up by itself. In this case I think it's all based on init scripts (as opposed to systemd configs).